# jQuery - Bind/UnBind events to image click event

Tags: jquery

I have a 'click' event associated with 6 image buttons.  It is currently possible to click the other 5 when 1 is clicked.  Is it possible to remove the click events on the other 5 temporarily? I have an animation that occurs on each, but if the user clicks multiple while the animation is running, it causes the animation to not function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than unbind the handlers and rebind them when the animation is done, why not just save the running state, and in your `click` callback check for it. Then when the animation is complete reset the state.

```
var running = false;

$('.button').click(function() {
    if(running) {
       return;
    }
    running = true;

    ...

    $(this).animate(..., function() {
        running = false;
    });

    ...
});
```

Comment: Great.  I had thought of that, but I didn't know the exact implementation.  Works awesome.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Just for anyone else, the implementation goes as follows:$("ul.accordion li:first").animate(
 {width: "0px"}, 
 {queue:false, duration:1000, 
  complete: function()
  {
   closeAnimationIsRunning = false;
  },
  step: function()
  {
  }
 }
);